# javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Me

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stEU4.png)
i am unable to solve this

give me any solution
Context Path:/CourierEP
Servlet Path:/home.xhtml
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy26.$Proxy98.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy26 does not "opens jdk.proxy26" to unnamed module @248a783b
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy26.$Proxy98.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy26 does not "opens jdk.proxy26" to unnamed module @248a783b
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBProxyInformation$1.doCompute(EJBProxyInformation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBProxyInformation$1.computeValue(EJBProxyInformation.java:72)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBProxyInformation$1.computeValue(EJBProxyInformation.java:66)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:228)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:210)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:116)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBProxyInformation.forViewType(EJBProxyInformation.java:242)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBLocator.getProxyInformation(EJBLocator.java:375)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBLocator.getProxyConstructor(EJBLocator.java:370)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBLocator.createProxyInstance(EJBLocator.java:387)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createProxy(EJBClient.java:161)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createProxy(EJBClient.java:156)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.RemoteViewManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(RemoteViewManagedReferenceFactory.java:105)
at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.ManagedReferenceFactoryToResourceReferenceFactoryAdapter.createResource(ManagedReferenceFactoryToResourceReferenceFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection.getResourceReference(AbstractResourceInjection.java:49)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection.injectResourceReference(AbstractResourceInjection.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectEEFields(Beans.java:309)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:71)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:117)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager.createBean(ViewScopeContextManager.java:122)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContext.get(ViewScopeContext.java:114)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:84)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:694)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
at org.jboss.as.jsf-injection//org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ForwardingELResolver.java:46)
at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:136)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2.redhat-00001//com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2.redhat-00001//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:126)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2.redhat-00001//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:175)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.2.redhat-00001//com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:202)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:140)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:287)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:181)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:328)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:143)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:595)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1654)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:152)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:566)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP05-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
... 49 more